# Socket.IO - `forceNew` vs `multiplex`

Tags: socket.io

The Socket.IO client library offers two options for the usage of Manager instances.

`forceNew` - Whether to create a new Manager instance.

`multiplex` - The opposite of `forceNew`: whether to reuse an existing Manager instance.

What happens if I pass both options with conflicting values? Which option takes precedence over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the source code of Socket.IO client:

```js
const newConnection =
  opts.forceNew ||
  opts["force new connection"] ||
  false === opts.multiplex ||
  sameNamespace;
```

(https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/index.ts#L55)

`forceNew` takes precedence if it is set to `true`, otherwise the client checks the value of `multiplex`.